# ngOnInit called multiple times after database changes in Angular and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngoninit

I have an app which is removing records from a Firestore database when the user clicks a button.  On console I can see that ngOnInit is being called once with the old data and then twice with the new updated data.  I am pushing these responses to an array so I end up with an array with 3 values instead of 1.

I have tried to pipe the subscribed data to take(1) but obviously it's returning the first one which is the old data before the change. I'm trying to implement onPush but I'm just getting a blank page.

swap-requests.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="ion-grid-width-md" *ngIf="user" >
    <tr *ngFor="let swaps of userSwapRequests;">
      <ion-row class="ion-padding" size="auto">
        <ion-col>
          <td *ngFor="let user of swaps.userCard">
            <ion-img [src]="user.images.small"
                     style="background: #F2F2F2;"></ion-img>
          </td>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <td *ngFor="let friend of swaps.friendCard">
            <ion-img [src]="friend.images.small"
                     style="background: #F2F2F2;"></ion-img>
            </td>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
<ion-row>
          <ion-button expand="block" color="danger" (click)="cancelSwap(swaps.swapData, swaps)">Cancel Swap</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

swap-requests.page.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-swap-requests',
  templateUrl: './swap-requests.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swap-requests.page.scss'],
})


export class SwapRequestsPage implements OnInit {
  user: any[] = [];
  userSwapRequests: any[] = [];
  currentFriend: User[] = [];
  swapArray: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private pokeService: PokemoncardsService,
    private ToastCtrl: ToastController,
  ) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.loadUser(environment.currentUser).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res: User[]) => {
      this.user.push(res);
      console.log('user', this.user);

      this.getUserPendingRequests();
    });
  }

  // get requests made by friends
  getUserPendingRequests() {
    this.userSwapRequests = [];

    let userSwapsList = this.user.map(data => data.swap_request);

    this.buildSwapArray(this.userSwapRequests, userSwapsList);
  }


  getFriend(value: any) {
    let friend: any[] = [];

    this.dataService.loadUser(value).subscribe((res: User[]) => {
      friend.push(res);
    });
    return friend;
  }

  getPokemonCard(number: any) {
    let result: any = [];
    this.pokeService.getPokeCard(number).subscribe(res => {
      result.push(res);
    });
    return result;
  }

  // create new array with API responses and friend's data
  async buildSwapArray(swaplist: any, userList: any) {

    userList.forEach((array: any) => {
      array.forEach((swap: any) => {
        let card: any;
        let usercard: any;
        let friend: any;

        Object.entries(swap).find(([key, value]) => {
          if (key === 'friend_card') {
            card = this.getPokemonCard(value);
            
          }
          if (key === 'user_card') {
            usercard = this.getPokemonCard(value);;
          }
          if (key === 'friend_id') {
            friend = this.getFriend(value);
          }
        })
        let newArray = {
          'friendCard': card,
          'userCard': usercard,
          'friend': friend,
          'swapData': swap,
        }
        swaplist.push(newArray);
        console.log('swapArray', this.userSwapRequests);
      })
    })
  }

  async cancelSwap(swapArray: any) {
    console.log('swapArray', swapArray);
    this.dataService.deleteSwapRequest(swapArray);

    let id = this.user.map(data => data.id);
    let friend: any;
    id.forEach((array) => {
      friend = array;
    })

    let friendArray: any = {
      'friend_card': swapArray.user_card,
      'friend_id': friend,
      'user_card': swapArray.friend_card,
    }
    let friendId = swapArray.friend_id;
    this.dataService.deleteFriendSwapRequest(friendArray, friendId);

    console.log('testsplice', this.userSwapRequests);
    const toast = await this.ToastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Swap confirmed',
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```

DataService:

```
export class User {
  id?: string;
  cards: [] = [];
  user_name: string | undefined;
  friends: [] = [];
  wishlist: [] = [];
  swaps: [] = [];
  pending_swap: [] = [];
  avatar: string | undefined;
  swap_request: [] = [];
  confirmed_swap: [] = [];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }

  loadUser(id: any): Observable<User[]> {
    const result = doc(this.firestore, `users/${id}`);
    return docData(result, { idField: 'id' }) as Observable<User[]>;
  }

  deleteSwapRequest(swapRequest: any) {
    const cardsIdRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${environment.currentUser}`);
    return updateDoc(cardsIdRef, {
      swap_request: arrayRemove(swapRequest)
    });
  }

  deleteFriendSwapRequest(swapRequest: any, friend:any) {
    const cardsIdRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${friend}`);
    return updateDoc(cardsIdRef, {
      pending_swap: arrayRemove(swapRequest)
    });
  }
```

Comment: And where is the code that renders app-swap-requests component?

Comment: So I had to research your question and I'm assuming you mean in the html <app-swap-requests></app-swap-requests>?.  I'm new to these frameworks/languages so I've not come across this before but I don't render this in the current html I have

Comment: Slightly misleading; your `ngOnInit` isn't being hit multiple times (component isn't being created multiple times), the subscription for `this.dataService.loadUser` is receiving data multiple times, I'd guess. What does your `DataService` look like? I have a feeling this issue is caused by mishandling your observables, but without seeing the rest of the picture, it's hard to say.

Comment: I've added the dataservice code to the question.  It probably is the observables, I'm struggling to get to grips with it.  For now, I've patched together a resolution, I realised that ngOnInit wasn't the issue but I bodged something together to get it to return the one correct result.